# connection.getConnetion() returns 404 code on WebSphere7

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-integration, websphere-7

I have implemented a REST service using Spring Integration.
When I try to access the service manually using main function, It is working fine. 
I also tested the service using REST Client in Google Chrome and that worked. But the service is coming back with responseCode 404 on WebSphere server. So I am facing the issue when I deploy the code on higher environment.

```
  URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/testRestService");
  URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");      
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
  Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

  //helper function that gets a string from a dom Document
  String input = jsonInput;
  wout.write(input.getBytes());        
  wout.flush();
  wout.close();

  // Response
  int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Is is dependent on server, so its coming back with response code 404 ? Do we need any server side configuration ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: My solution resolved with Apache HTTP client API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Apache HTTP Client and the code is working on WebSphere now. Still I am not able to find the reason why java.net.HttpURLConnection was not working on WebSphere.

Please find my updated code below :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost postRequest = null;
        StringEntity inputEntity = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try{


            //RETREIVE WEB SERVICE URL FROM DB
            String callbackURL = "http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/testRestService";
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            postRequest = new HttpPost(callbackURL);            
            String inputData = request.toString();

            inputEntity = new StringEntity(inputData);
            inputEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            postRequest.setEntity(inputEntity);

            response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);



            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201 && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            //System.out.println("HTTP Response Code :"+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            LOGGER.debug("HTTP Response Code :"+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }finally{
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            httpClient = null;
            postRequest = null;
            inputEntity = null;
            response = null;
        }
```

Comment: Use a network monitor such as wireshark (or there's one built-in to eclipse) to compare the data from each client. Since you are already using Spring, consider using the `RestTemplate` it will eliminate much of the boilerplate code you need when coding the clients directly.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use different `ContentType` for `URLConnection` and for `httpClient`?

Show, please, your REST service config: `404` means `Not found`. Therefore you use (or don't) some options in request which makes it non-matching for the server's `RequestMapping`.

Comment: I edited the question. I have pasted the unit testing core here ,so mentioned wrong content type. I am using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

Comment: If there is something missing in the request parameter then why the same code is working when I test it inside and main program and jetty server. Its creating issue only when I deploy it on higher environment on Wbsphere7 application server.

Comment: You don't count hehe the IBM JVM, where UrlConnection may have a bit different impl...